# Customer password reset in magento 2: "Something went wrong while resetting customer password"

Tags: magento2, change-password

I want to change customer password from backend. I clicked on reset password but I am getting error as lik:

> Something went wrong while resetting customer password.

Comment: clear cache and check log file..may be old  password not match..

Comment: hey bro i am asking about magento 2. here i am not reseting i want to send password reset link to customer

Comment: you can check with https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7548

Comment: i checked but still i am getting error

Answer (score 0):

Just run below query :

ALTER TABLE customer_entity ADD failures_num SMALLINT( 6 ) NULL DEFAULT '0'; ALTER TABLE customer_entity ADD first_failure NULL DEFAULT '0';

Comment: Not working these queries!

Comment: What errors do you see in exception log? Before running direct SQL on tables as a band aid it’s advisable to find the root cause and the exception log will help diagnose the problem. Also running these “quick” SQL queries has short term benefits but is far from recommended best practise.